# Segmentation fault (core dumped) - how to fix my code?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, coredump

The program finds a char with the smallest ascii code in a string and outputs it. My problem is in message: Segmentation fault(core dumped). Why and Where does it occur? 
Thanks for attention.

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <string.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>    

int main(void) {    

char* str = NULL;    
int* mincode = NULL;    
int* count = NULL;    
char* mincodeChar = NULL;


 str = (char *) malloc(50 * sizeof(char));
 mincode = (int *) malloc(1 * sizeof(int));
 count = (int *) malloc(1 * sizeof(int));

 if (NULL == str || NULL == mincode || NULL == count){
        printf("Alloc error");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

fgets(str, 50, stdin);

printf("your string: ");
puts(str);

*mincode = (int)(str[*count]);
*mincodeChar = *(str + *count);

 for (*count = 0; str[*count] != '\0'; (*count)++) {

    if( (int)str[*count] < (*mincode)) {
    (*mincode) = (int)str[*count];
    mincodeChar = (str + *count);
    printf("%c", *mincodeChar);
    }
}

printf("your character: ");
printf("%c", *mincodeChar);

free(str);
free(mincode);
free(count);

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Why are you dynamically allocating memory, when you have compile-time fixed sizes? Especially, why allocate memory for *one* `int`? Why not use a simple `int` variable?

Comment: 1) at `*mincode = (int)(str[*count]);` : `*count` is uninitialized.

Comment: Also please see [this discussion about casting the result of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: Why so much dynamic memory allocation, by the way? How is having `int *count` better than just plain `int count`?

Comment: In addition to previous comments: a debugger would have told you exactly at which line the segfault occured. Learn to use a debugger, it will save you a lot of time in the future.

Comment: It's written in the task - not to use ordinary var's. So, that's why

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude What do u mean "uninitialized" ?

Comment: It wasn't me posting that comment, but you have to remember that `malloc` only *allocate* memory, it doesn't initialize it in any way. So when you use `*count` before the loop you are getting an *indeterminate* value which will probably be very wrong and you might go out of bounds of the memory allocated for `str`.

Comment: Also note that `str[*count]` and `*(str + *count)` are the same.

Comment: [fix like this](http://ideone.com/fDoU3j)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would appear that you need to learn how to use a debugger to step line-by-line through your code, which will likely allow you to easily pinpoint the nature and location of the issue you're having. Using a debugger is, for all intents and purposes, required knowledge for any programmer. For more info, see [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 4):

```
char* mincodeChar = NULL;
....
*mincodeChar = *(str + *count);
```

You dereference a NULL pointer.

The lessons to take from this are:

1. Always initialize you variables to a **valid** value as soon as possible.
2. Check pointers before dereferencing.

Comment: but there is  mincodeChar = (str + *count); and then i dereference mincodeChar.  why Doesn't it work anyway? Does it cause a problem?

Comment: @Sergei, `*mincodeChar = *(str + *count);` **is not** the same as `mincodeChar = (str + *count);`. The first accesses pointed-to values, the second accesses the pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't check but

```
*mincode = (int)(str[*count]);
*mincodeChar = *(str + *count);
```

*count* contains a value not initialized. So it can be 0 like, more probably, something like 492892911039...  never understood the randomness of the not initialized variables. And in this case you are attempting to open the position at 492892911039.... SIGSEGV? if you want 0 or explicitely set it to 0 or rather then malloc() call calloc(). Then the same as the others... why you allocate a single variable? ... It can happen, but is for foreign constraints, an example is when you call some API functions that only accept a void *... but when is possible to avoid is better avoid. Not only for lazyness. Most implementations of malloc are list.So more you allocate more long becomes this list that at each new allocation must be scored. So a bit it slows down your malloc(). Not of course in this case... but ever better allocate few big block of memory rather than a lot small

Answer (score 0):

```
*mincodeChar = *(str + *count);
```

You're dereferencing a NULL pointer, instead of initializing it to NULL at the beginning, do

```
char* mincodeChar = new char();
```

or

```
char* mincodeChar = malloc(sizeof(char));
```

also count is allocated but not initialized, when you set mincode with it, it could be anywhere from 0 to the 32 bit integer limit
When you're allocating pointers with malloc() it does not initialize a value, so make sure to assign a value soon after allocation, before use, because it could be completely junk values that could mess up your program, I always make sure to either set the value soon after, or initialize all of the memory to 0s with memset so I know it is good to use. Doesn't matter here but once you start to use them in bigger programs or do more complex things with them, it can be an issue.